# Reference request: $q$-gamma, $q$-polygamma, $q$-Pochhammer.

Tags: reference-request, gamma-function, polygamma, q-series, pochhammer-symbol

I'm trying to solve a problem related to a few difficult series and am using Mathematica to hammer out the difficult bits. The problem is that `QPochhammer`,`QPolyGamma`, and `QGamma` and I know next to nothing about them! The Wolfram MathWorld passages on them are unfriendly introductions, **so I am asking for recommendations to references which introduce these functions and their properties (both by themselves and in tandem with each other.)**

I am aware of some references, I am just here to find additional ones and to see if anyone would recommend any in particular.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_q-analogs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I just found a good one: *Basic Hypergeometric Series* by George Gasper and Mizan Rahman. Introduces hypergeometric series and covers $q$-gamma, $q$-beta, and $q$-binomials within the first 50 pages.

Comment: As a quick question, are there any equations that the basic hypergeometric series can solve?